# JCR jackrabbit pagination

Tags: java, apache, jackrabbit, jcr, jsr170

I'm using the following JCR-SQL2 Query to retrieve some files from [jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) repository

```
    SELECT id FROM [nt:file]
  WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/repo/cms])
```

How can I use pagination in jackrabbit to retrieve only a limit number of files.

I mean the COUNT in MS-SQL or LIMIT in MySQL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
Query query = queryManager.createQuery(queryString, Query.SQL);
QueryImpl q = (QueryImpl) query;
q.setLimit(10);
q.setOffset(10); // Start from the 10:th file
QueryResult result = q.execute();
```

Comment: it seems that jackrabbit did not implement the setLimit() and setOffset() methods and i get this error : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TODO: JCRRMI-26 .... which means this method will be implemented later

Comment: @Ammar: AFAICS you access Jackrabbit through RMI. Jackrabbit itself does support the setLimit() and setOffset() method. The error you are getting is from the RMI layer which does not (yet) implement these methods.

Comment: This is not enough for pagination, what about total count?